# Networkx plotting - paint the edge labels according to the colours of the edges

Tags: matplotlib, plot, label, networkx, edges

Is it possible to colour the text of the labels according to the colour of the edges they belong to? I tried to do this with `font_color` but got following error: `ValueError: dict_values(['r', 'g', 'b', 'm', .... 'y']) is not a valid value for color`.

My plotting now looks like this:

```
colors = nx.get_edge_attributes(graph, 'color').values()
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, with_labels=True, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', edge_color=colors)
edge_labels_bidirectional = dict([((u, v,), d['initial_balance'])
                    for u, v, d in graph.edges(data=True)])


nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(graph, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels_bidirectional,
                             label_pos=0.3, font_size=7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels` only takes a string as the `font_color` argument (and not a list or a dictionnary, doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html)), you'll have to call `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`  for each edge and draw each label separately with the corresponding color.

See code below (network is adapted from [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/basic/plot_simple_graph.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-basic-plot-simple-graph-py)):

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(1, 5)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(4, 5)

pos = {1: (0, 0), 2: (-1, 0.3), 3: (2, 0.17), 4: (4, 0.255), 5: (5, 0.03)}

cmap=plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,G.number_of_edges()))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,edge_color=cmap)
[nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels={e:i},font_color=cmap[i]) for i,e in enumerate(G.edges())]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me if I could somehow merge the label definition I already have above and the one you suggested? I need to color the text on both sides of the channels.

Comment: Without the data it's a little hard to tell unfortunately. But on paper you should be able to make it work yes.